# jQuery DatePicker Min Max dates

Tags: jquery, datepicker, maxdate, mindate

I have the jQuery date picker setup and working but would like help with setting the minDate and maxDate options.  My current code is below (without these options).  How can I set the minDate as 3 months before the defaultDate, and maxDate as 28days after the defaultDate?

```
var expdisp = $("#expdisp").attr("value");

$("#expirydate" ).datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    defaultDate: expdisp,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
});
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$(function() {

    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: '-3M',
        maxDate: '+28D',
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kGjdL/114/)

**UPDATE**

You can calculate tour max and min valid dates from the default date, then assign it to the date picker.

```
var expdisp = $("#expdisp").attr("value");

$("#expirydate" ).datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    defaultDate: expdisp,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,

    minDate: '-3M',
    maxDate: '+28D',
});
```

[Update Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kGjdL/120/)

Comment: This is calculated from 'today' and not what is set in the 'defaultDate'

Comment: Thanks for this, it's still calculating the min/max from today. I've sorted it now though - I'm calculating the values in PHP and then just passing them when initiating the datePicker.

Comment: @Rob - because I set the default value as Today in demo. Glad to help :), please upvote and accept answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: I accepted the answer, although try changing the default value in the demo and you'll see it still calculates from today.

Answer (score 2):

**maxDate** :- Sets the maximum date that can be selected. Accepts a date object or a relative number. For example: +7, or a string such as +6m.

**minDate :-** Sets the minimum date that can be selected. Accepts a number, date object, or string.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#date").datepicker({
      minDate: -3,
      maxDate: "1w"
  });
```

});

Refer:-[set Minimum and maximum date to jquery datepicker](http://goo.gl/xE3ZFr)

Answer (score 0):

Your could try:

```
var expdisp = $("#expdisp").attr("value");

$("#expirydate" ).datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    defaultDate: expdisp,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,

    minDate: -3M,
    maxDate: +28D
});
```

Comment: I did try this but the values are calculated from 'today' and not whatever is in 'defaultDate'

Comment: Ooppps. How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395771/jquery-ui-datepicker-maxdate Just pass your date to the function and use it in var maxDate = new Date(defaultDate);

Answer (score 0):

You can also use specific date ranges. I added a min beginning date with a +14D max. You just need to remember to stay consistent with your date format and use "/" instead of "-" between MM/DD/YYYY.

```js
$('#Date').datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  minDate: '10/19/2016',
  maxDate: '+14D',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[id$=tbDate]').datepicker({   
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
         minDate: '-0D',
         maxDate: '+28D',
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var startDate = new Date(); // Now
var endDate = new Date();
endDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 30); // Set now + 30 days as the new date
$('#myDatePicker').datepicker('setEndDate', endDate);//1st set  end date
$('#myDatePicker').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);//
```