# how to set max & min in Input type date on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, html

how can i set min and max to date in input type date

i try

```
<input name="DOB" id="DOB" class="enterAddressFormField" placeholder="Date of birthday&nbsp;" size="50" maxlength="60" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" type="text" onfocus="this.type='date';this.max=='1979-12-31';this.min=='1910-01-01';this.setAttribute('onfocus','');this.blur();this.focus();">
```

and

```
<input name="DOB" id="DOB" class="enterAddressFormField" placeholder="Date of birthday&nbsp;" size="50" maxlength="60" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" min="1910-01-02"  max="1979-12-31" type="text" onfocus="this.type='date';this.setAttribute('onfocus','');this.blur();this.focus();">
```

Comment: Please please do not use inline code like that, the readability is horrible. Use external event handlers.

Comment: You're using `type="text"`, and inputs of that type don't understand the `min` and `max` attributes. Inputs of type `"date"` are supposed to, but I don't know of any platform on which they actually do (though I'd love to be wrong).

Comment: @SterlingArcher Can you tell me how, please :)

Comment: @Pointy i ues type="text" to show the placeholder

Comment: If you use `type="text"` the user will have to type in a date. If you use `type="date"` the user will get the native iOS date control. However, as I said, I don't think Safari supports `min` or `max` for date controls. Personally I think the native date control is user-hostile anyway, but for touch screen use you really need something better than typing with the keyboard.

Comment: @Pointy - That is correct. `min` and `max` are not supported currently. Check here for the latest support https://caniuse.com/#search=input%20date

Answer (score 0):

You should use datepicker js

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  maxDate:'+1m +10d',
  minDate: -10
 });
```

here check it out

https://makitweb.com/set-minimum-maximum-date-jquery-ui-datepicker/

[jQuery DatePicker Min Max dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646008/jquery-datepicker-min-max-dates)