# minDate and maxDate Options not working in BeyondAdmin theme, mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, datepicker

I am trying to add minDate and maxDates in datepicker of **BeyondAdmin** Theme not **simple jquery datepicker**, but it's not working. Following is myjquery code to set dates :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#id-date-picker').datepicker({
         format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
         minDate: new Date(),
         maxDate: new Date(),
      });
</script>
```

and I have used razor syntax like this

```
@Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor(t => t.EntryDate).Id("id-date-picker")
```

Date Format is working fine but not min and max Dates. Has somebody used this theme, can somebody please help me out? Thank you

Comment: Seems like your razor syntax is incorrect

Comment: If your datepicker is working fine but, mindate and maxdate are not working. You can check for default options in datepicker js(which is used by the theme). There must a difference in default parameters. Like rather than "minDate" parameter, it might be "min" only. I hope you understand.

Comment: Setting both the min and max to today's date does not make much sense :)

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? How the max and min dates are behaving now and how you want them to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery DatePicker Min Max dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646008/jquery-datepicker-min-max-dates)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke I have just given for the reference, these are dynamic dates which will be getting from model

Comment: @Hazard no datepicker is showing fine on screen

Comment: @Sabyasachi Mishra I am using beyondadmin theme datepicker not simple jquery datepicker

Comment: @SamGhatak I am trying to enable only min and max Range selection, others should be disabled on datepicker

Comment: @Rohit Arora I could not find any minDate, min or StartDate in the BeyondAdmin datepciker.js, I need to add this in js file =s

Comment: @MahrukhMehmood if you can't find them, you can add it. Create your logic or just copy original datepicker's logic and apply it in your datepicker.

Comment: I'll try to add this into their datepicker.js file