# jQuery UI datepicker issues with today's date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to setup the jQuery UI datepicker to have minDate of today and maxDate to at least 18 years; if they choose less than 18 years, it should throw an error:

```
$('#dateofbirth').datepicker({changeMonth:true,changeYear:true,
minDate: 0, maxDate: '-18Y'});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is already answered:

See this discussion:-
 [jQuery DatePicker Min Max dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646008/jquery-datepicker-min-max-dates)

Try something like this :

```
 $(function() {

        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
            changeYear: true,
            minDate: '-3M',
            maxDate: '+28D',
        });
    });
```

change min and maxDate according to your needs